# Why does the postgresql function return an integer?

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_zp(zp real default 70) RETURNS real AS $$
DECLARE
    percent_zp real := 0.15;
    zp_new real;
BEGIN
    IF zp > 70 THEN  zp_new = zp;
    ELSIF zp < 0 THEN  zp_new = zp;
    ELSE zp_new = zp * percent_zp+zp;
    END IF;
    RETURN zp_new;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

execute

```
select * from get_zp(50);
```

why does the function return 50???

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: No it does not. Ваша функция вполне нормально возвращает 57.5 (float4)

Comment: Отправляю функции целое число 50. Возвращает 50. 
Отправлю число 50.0 получаю 57.57 как положено.
Почему при отправке 50 возвращает   50?